# Prove that $\dim G(\lambda,T_{\Bbb{C}})=\dim G(\bar{\lambda},T_{\Bbb{C}})$

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the following theorem in *Linear Algebra Done Right*.

$V$ is a vector space and $T$ is an operator on $V$. Denote the complexification of $V$ and $T$, respectively, by $V_{\Bbb{C}}$ and $T_{\Bbb{C}}$. Also, in the book, multiplicity of an eigen-value is defined as $\dim G(\lambda,T)$ where $G(\lambda,T)$ is the generalized eigen-space. The theorem $9.17$ is trying to prove

$$\dim G(\lambda,T_{\Bbb{C}})=\dim G(\bar{\lambda},T_{\Bbb{C}})$$

I don't understand how routine arguments work here! I can understand that if $u+iv \in G(\lambda,T)$ then $u-iv \in G(\bar{\lambda},T)$ but the rest is not too much clear for me. Any hint is appreciated.

[image]
[image]

Comment: When you write \text{dim} instead of \dim, then you don't get proper spacing in things like $A\dim B$ or $A\dim(B)$ (I include both of those so that you can see the context-dependent nature of the spacing). (This was conspicuous in your posting before I clicked on "edit", and I edited accordingly.) $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Thanks for teaching some typesetting issues. :)

Comment: "Routine arguments" means probably that you should show the linear independence simply using the definition of "lin.indep." and the fact that $u_1+iv_1,\dots,u_m+iv_m$ is a basis of $G(\lambda,T_{\Bbb C})$ and then, again with definition, you should show that it spans $G(\bar{\lambda},T_{\Bbb C})$.

Comment: @paf: Would you please write some hints or an answer! I couldn't get anything! ;)

Comment: You can see my answer below!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Linear independence:** let $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_m\in\Bbb C$ s.t. $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^m \alpha_k(u_k-iv_k)=0$. We apply complex conjugation: $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^m \overline{\alpha_k}(u_k+iv_k)=0$. Since $(u_1+iv_1,\dots,u_m+iv_m)$ is linearly independent, we see that $\forall k\in\{1,\dots,m\},\overline{\alpha_k}=0$ thus $\forall k,\,\alpha_k=0$.

**Spanning:** let $u_0+iv_0=u_0-i(-v_0)=u-iv\in G(\overline{\lambda},T_{\Bbb C})$. By definition, there is an integer $j$ s.t. $(T_{\Bbb C}-\bar{\lambda}I)^j(u-iv)=0$. By Lemma 9.12, we have $(T_{\Bbb C}-\lambda I)^j(u+iv)=0$. Thus $u+iv\in G(\lambda,T_{\Bbb C})$ and, since $(u_1+iv_1,\dots,u_m+iv_m)$ spans $G(\lambda,T_{\Bbb C})$, there exist $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_m\in\Bbb C$ s.t.  $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^m \alpha_k(u_k+iv_k)=u+iv$. By conjugating, we see that $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^m \overline{\alpha_k}(u_k-iv_k)=u-iv$, hence $(u_1-iv_1,\dots,u_m-iv_m)$ spans $G(\bar{\lambda},T_{\Bbb C})$.

Comment: Conjugation was not defined on $V_{\Bbb{C}}$ in the book! :)